# NGINX Server to Redirect to Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, dokuwiki

The following i want to achieve:

On Server A there is docker installed. There are, lets say, 3 Containers:

- Container 1: App1, ip: 172.17.0.2, network: mynet, Simple HTML Welcome page, accessible by port 80
- Container 2: App2, ip: 172.17.0.3, network: mynet, a Wiki System -> dokuwiki, accessible by port 8080
- Container 3: App3, ip: 172.17.0.4, network: mynet, something else

You can see, every container are in the same Docker network. The Containers are accessible by different Ports.

The Clients on the same network needs to access all of the Containers. I can't use DNS in this case (Reverse Proxy via VHOST), because i am not control the DNS. My Goal:

- Container 1 : accessible via http://myserver.home.local/app1/
- Container 2 : accessible via http://myserver.home.local/app2/
- Container 3 : accessible via http://myserver.home.local/app3/

What i did to solve this is the following: Add another Container with nginx, and do proxy_pass to the containers. I use the official nginx image (docker pull nginx), then i mount my custom config into the /etc/nginx/conf.d dir. My Config looks like the follow:

```
server {

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index:  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://app1/
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2:8080/
    }

    location /app3/ {
        proxy_pass http://app3/
    }

}
```

The app1 does work. The app2 does not: It prints me some ugly html output. In the Browser Web Console, i see a lot of 404. I guess that has something to do with Reverse / Rewrite of nginx, because, the app2 is Dokuwiki. I also add the apache ProxyPassReverse equivalent for nginx, without success.

I just do not know what to do in this case, or where to start. How can i know, what to be rewrite? I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I'm guessing the docuwiki setup references static assets. You probably need to configure it so it knows it's not hosted on the base url `/`, but instead `/app2`. Otherwise the internally generated links to static assets will be wrong.

Comment: Both https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:basedir and https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:baseurl might be relevant.

Comment: If app2 is listening on port 8080 then you need to specify that as `proxy_pass http://app2:8080/`

Comment: @HansKilian im sorry, I'm already doing that. My mistake. I corrected the Post.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:
As soon as I use the dokuwiki `basedir` / `baseurl` config, the proxy is working as expected. To do so, edit the `dokuwiki.php` configuration file located in the `conf` folder:

> conf/dokuwiki.php

change the following settings to your environment

```
$conf['basedir']     = '/dokuwiki';
$conf['baseurl']     = '';
```